# How to create a base64-encoded string from a local file image in javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I have been trying to convert an image file from my local machine but it seems not working for me. 
I don't want to upload the image using an input because I'm only having the image path in production and i want to store the base64 string. but if there is a better way i can handle this then i don't mind

```
        const reader = new FileReader();
         const file = new File([imgUrl], { type: "image/png" });
        console.log(file);
        reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.result);
        }, false);

        const data = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return data;
        }
        const img = "localhost:8080/start app abnner.png"; // my image path
        getDataUrl(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the result property of your object (see [FileReader API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result))

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(image) // assuming "image" is your file
reader.result // here is your base64 string
```

So in your case, it should be:

```
const data = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
return data.result;
```

---

I had to do something like this once, so I made a little plugin if you want: [encode-image-uri](https://github.com/EmmanuelBeziat/encode-image-uri). It has the advantage of using promises, so you’re 100% sure that you’re calling any function only when the conversion is done and your data is ready.

Comment: i am getting this instead File {name: "[object Object]", lastModified: 1587049668414, lastModifiedDate: Thu Apr 16 2020 16:07:48 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 35, …}name: "[object Object]"lastModified: 1587049668414lastModifiedDate: Thu Apr 16 2020 16:07:48 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time) {}webkitRelativePath: ""size: 35type: ""__proto__: File
index.html:98 data:application/octet-stream;base64,bG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvc3RhcnQgYXBwIGFibm5lci5wbmc=
from looks its not treating it as an image